# How do I keep security settings when I restore a database from another server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, powershell

I have two SQL Servers and I want to do a backup on one of them and then restore that on the other server. The catch is that the database already exists on the server I'm restoring to, and I want to keep the security settings the way they are on the server I'm restoring to.

The other catch is that I want to do all of this from PowerShell, so no GUI operations.

Or is this maybe the wrong solution to the problem. Is there maybe another way to move the data without doing a backup/restore and keeping the security settings?

Comment: What do you mean by "security settings"? Logins, users, roles, object permissions? And what version and edition of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Personally after a DB restore on a different server I use a stored proc do set security. You can script with posh the execution of stored after restore have success

Comment: @Pondlife Yes. The logins, users and roles are differend on the two servers(different service accounts etc). We are using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise on both servers.

Answer (score 0):

In my environment we use Powershell scripts with Red Gate Compare Professional to restore databases and persist security plus database object differences. The process is fairly simple

1. Create a Red Gate snapshot of the destination database. Using the Red Gate command-line tool. The file it generates is very small and only contain users, permissions, and objects--basically everything except for the data.
2. Restore the source database over the destination database using T-SQL
3. Use the command-line Red Gate tools to compare and synchronize snapshot created in step to the nearly restored database. Any security or object changes are restored.

This solution does require purchasing the Professional edition of SQL Compare and installing the tool on the development server from which the script can be executed. All of this can easily be put into SQL Agent job. The use of Powershell is really kind of basic since we're just executing sqlcompare.exe

Answer (score 0):

There is [an article here](http://jongurgul.wordpress.com/2011/05/11/sql-server-instance-security-scripting-permissions/) explaining how to script SQL Server permissions through SMO via PowerShell. Your scenario would then be to script permissions from your initial DB before restoring the backup, then execute the generated script after backup has been restored.